# Hibernate Criteria Class for making complex queries to database

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, nhibernate-mapping

I'm developing a web application based on **Struts2 Framework** for implementing the MVC, and **Hibernate3** for accesing the database by means of **DAOs**, and **DTOs** for mapping the **relational** objects in the **database**. In the Hibernate context, I would like to know the reach of the **Criteria Clases** for making complex queries, and also if there is another option for doing such tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "reach," I'm assuming you mean the domain of complex, SQL-related queries that can be constructed via chaining method calls through a specific Criteria object (as discussed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)).

In my experience, most common tasks that rely on result filtering, ordering, projection, grouping, logical conjunctive or disjunctive statements, or subquerying can be carried out by mutating a `Criteria` object in the expected ways.

As an alternative, you can use [`Session.createSQLQuery`](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29) to construct a raw SQL query, then [`Query.list`](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29) or [`Query.executeUpdate`](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) to execute it. For example:

```
Sesion sess = getSession();
Query mySelect = sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * from foo");
List<Entity> results = mySelect.list();

Query myUpdate = sess.createSQLQuery("DELETE * from foo where bar = \"boz\"");
int updateCount = myUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

Obviously, you'll want to extend from this naive example, but you get the idea.